# Invalid version value: 4.0~alpha4 during startup

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-4.0

We are testing the latest cassandra-4.0 on Centos 7 using a clean database.  When we started cassandra the first time, everything is fine.  However, when we stop and restart cassandra, we got the following error and the db refuses to startup:

```
ERROR [main] 2020-07-16 14:25:11,330 CassandraDaemon.java:789 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid version value: 4.0~alpha4
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.CassandraVersion.<init>(CassandraVersion.java:64)
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableHeaderFix.fixNonFrozenUDTIfUpgradeFrom30(SSTableHeaderFix.java:84)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:250)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:650)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:767)
```

Comment: I suggest to file a JIRA against Cassandra, or try the proposed beta1 version (see Cassandra dev mailing list)

Comment: where can i get beta1 version sir?

Comment: https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/cassandra/4.0-beta1/

Comment: thanks sir, but how can i edit cassandra.repo 

[cassandra]
name=Apache Cassandra
baseurl=https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/cassandra/4.0-beta1 
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/KEYS

like thatt?

Comment: as I understand, at this stage you need to install package "manually"... or wait until it's approved officially & published